# Android Source Code Compile errors with lib32ncurses5-dev, lib32readline5-dev, etc. on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: android

I have downloaded the source code for Android from http://source.android.com/source/index.html and now I am trying to build it but I am finding different types of library errors. Although I have completely followed the instruction from there but in vain. Could you help me for compiling it. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with JDK 1.6 and all listed libraries install. I have downloaded android-2.3.7_r1.

Error is: make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/adb_intermediates/adb] Error 1

```
I am also unable to install these packages:
lib32ncurses5-dev ia32-libs 
lib32readline5-dev lib32z-dev 

I am getting error: 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package lib32ncurses5-dev 
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs 
E: Unable to locate package lib32readline5-dev 
E: Unable to locate package lib32z-dev
```

Yours,

Comment: You may want to include the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very useful link for Android compilation: http://e-xiao.blogspot.com/2011/10/resolve-build-errors-for-android-234.html
AND
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20795

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem and I've downloaded and installed some of the libraries manually, from here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+package/lib32ncurses5-dev

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+package/lib32readline5-dev

**I think you don't need *ia32-libs* and *lib32z-dev* if you're running Ubuntu 32.** If you're running Ubuntu 64 though, you may still need them. Please confirm this information!

Comment: Sorry, I'm running Ubuntu "lucid" (10.04), not "oneiric" (11.10), so the only one you've got (if you're running a 32bits install) is apparently [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/lib32ncurses5-dev](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/lib32ncurses5-dev). Sorry, hope it helps somehow!

Answer (score 0):

Did you run this command?

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl zlib1g-dev libc6-dev lib32ncurses5-dev ia32-libs \
  x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32readline5-dev lib32z-dev \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos python-markdown \
  libxml2-utils
```

And follow all the instructions on this page?
http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Comment: It definitely looks like you didn't run that command, the dependencies are missing.